# Restoring 1 GB to original 4 GB

Tags: usb-storage, usb-flash-drive

I tried installing some Chrome OS on my 4 GB flashdrive and it got formatted and whatnot. Now I formatted it once more with Windows and it is now 1 GB and no longer 4 GB.

I read somewhere that I could use partition wizard or something like that? Didn't finish reading because it got all complex.

Comment: PS: 4 gb is 512 MB.

Comment: @Hennes - **WHAT?**

Comment: 4 gigabit is 1/2 gigaByte is 512 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Disk Management

Delete the 1GB Volume on the flash disk

Create a new Volume at the full 4GB

Take a look here for more details on what to do.  It's for XP, but shouldn't matter if you're on 7 or above either: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309000

Comment: thanks, this worked!
Another way i found during my research was to use EaseUS Partition Master :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your flashdrive has the wrong values in its partitioning scheme. This is easy to fix without extra software.

First copy all data you want to keep (the next steps will erase all on the drive).

Go to start, run and type `diskpart`.
In diskpart `select disk 1` (Make sure that you have the right disk here, the number can differ)
then issue a `clean` command to wipe **all** old information.

The next time you insert the drive you will be asked if you want to initialise it (as a 4GB) disk.